# Last event of a user

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics

could you help me.

I have the query below that works and meets my need but I don't know if it was done in the best way and if there is a less complex way to build the query.

Purpose: Capture the last event (event_name) of the user_id, only one per user and the most recent.
Query developed in Bigquery environment for GA4 event tables

```
    CAST(CONCAT(SUBSTR(t2.event_date, 0, 4), '-', SUBSTR(t2.event_date, 5, 2), '-', SUBSTR(t2.event_date, 7, 2)) AS DATE) AS event_timestamp,
    DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE("UTC-3"),CAST(CONCAT(SUBSTR(t2.event_date, 0, 4), '-', SUBSTR(t2.event_date, 5, 2), '-', SUBSTR(t2.event_date, 7, 2)) AS DATE),day) AS days_ult_event,
    t1.user_id,
    t2.event_name
  FROM (
    SELECT
      MAX(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp)) event_timestamp,
      USER_ID
    FROM
      `events_*`
    WHERE
      user_id IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY
      2) t1
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
    DISTINCT user_id,
      event_name,
      event_date,
      TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp) AS event_timestamp
    FROM
      `events_*`) t2
  ON
    t1.user_id = t2.user_id
    AND t1.event_timestamp = t2.event_timestamp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach works, however it's not so great, a little hard to read. To return the latest event for a user try using row_number() window function:

```
with _latest as (
SELECT user_id,
  event_name,
  event_date,
  TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp) AS event_timestamp,
  row_number() over (partition by user_id order by TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp) desc) as rn
FROM `events_*`
)
select *
from _latest
where rn=1
```

BigQuery best practice suggest using Offset:

```
SELECT user_id, event_name, event_date,
    array_agg(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp) order by event_timestamp desc) [offset(0)] AS event_timestamp
FROM `events_*`
group by user_id, event_name, event_date
```

Comment: Good answer, but can be improved by handling the time zone differences between event_date and event_timestamp.  Unless they are both UTC, you will need to convert the event_timestamp to your Property's time zone. https://analyticscanvas.com/3-reasons-your-ga4-data-doesnt-match/

Comment: @pmo511, please refer to the documentation stating this is the best practice.

Comment: @MaximKirilov, I was a tad flippant with that statement, though i need read it in some BQ exam prep material a while back. In this scenario where there is only 1 field to partition and order by row_number() is possibly more performant (and easier to read?). However, in my experience (and potentially backing up the exam prep claim) the more complicated the window function (esp. the more columns in the sort order) the exponentially slower they become compared to array_agg.